# DateTime.TryParseExact not parsing as expected for yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I am trying to parse datetime from string and my code is not parsing the datetime.

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DateTime sendingDateTime;
        bool parseSendingDateTime = DateTime.TryParseExact(
                "20180409090001",
                "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss",
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                DateTimeStyles.None, out sendingDateTime);

        Console.WriteLine(parseSendingDateTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your input has no `-` but your format string does - one of these is wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like taking risk to answer your question since Chris [perfectly explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49779894/datetime-tryparseexact-not-parsing-as-expected-for-yyyy-mm-ddthhmmss#comment86575365_49779894) what is wrong, here the *proper* format for your string.

```
bool parseSendingDateTime = DateTime.TryParseExact(
                "20180409090001",
                "yyyyMMddHHmmss",
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                DateTimeStyles.None, out sendingDateTime);
```